# how do we check a null value and a length at the same time in a template condition?

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically I have a data that sometimes the value is null and sometimes the value is an empty array , it should still render the template if leaseApDto is not null or leaseApDto.length not equal to 0.

I tried to use the condition `model.leaseApDto !== null || model.leaseApDto.length !=== 0` but they dont seem to work together even if its an OR condition.

Any idea ? would really appreciate it. Thanks.

leaseApDto with a null value

[image]

leaseApDto with an empty value but is an array

[image]

#code

```
  <div *ngIf="model.leaseApDto !== null || model.leaseApDto.length !=== 0" class="transaction-lease-details-list">
        <div class="description-header">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="transaction-lease-details-content list-row-divider">
                <div class="transaction-lease-details-left-label">
                    Current Base Rent (Annual)
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, wouldn't replacing || with && resolve your issue?

Or you can simply use

`*ngIf="model.leaseApDto?.length"`

? is the safe navigation operator and helps to decrease a lot of code, and also helpful in such cases.

I would personally add the check to model too, like `*ngIf="model?.leaseApDto?.length"`

Answer (score 1):

The condition has to be model.leaseApDto !== null && model.leaseApDto.length !== 0